# The number of partitions between two fixed partitions

Tags: co.combinatorics, generating-functions, partitions

Given two partitions M and N, with $M_i \leq N_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq  \max\{l(M),l(N)\}$. Is there a formula for the generating function: $$\sum_{\lambda:  M_i\leq \lambda_i\leq  N_i} q^{|\lambda|}$$

I remember seeing a determinant formula before, the elements of the determinant being q-binomial coefficients. But now I can't find it.

Comment: Maybe this is only a minor technicality, but the upper bound on $i$ is throwing me off.  Can you clarify?  For example, between (2,1,1) and (2,2) are we allowing longer partitions such as (2,1,1,1) and/or larger partitions such as (2,2,1)?  Or are there zero partitions in between these (presumably because of padding by zeros)?  I would be happier if $l(M) \le l(N)$, but the way the upper bound on $i$ is written goes against this.

Comment: @PeterDukes Well, let's restrict our attention to what's called 'containment order', i.e. the containment of corresponding Ferrers diagram. (2,1,1) and (2,2) would not be comparable, under this order.

Comment: OK good.  I am outside my comfort level here, but I agree this should be well known.  Do you vaguely recall if the determinant was of some Hessenberg matrix?

Comment: Well i have found it now, see my answer below @PeterDukes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note on enumeration of partitions contained in a given shape

by Ira M. Gessel and Nicholas Loehr

link:
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379509004819