# Partitions contained in staircase shape

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $\lambda_n=\{n-1,n-2,\dots,1\}$ be a partition of staircase shape. Let $f(n,k)=\#\{|\mu|=k|\mu\leq\lambda_n\}$ and $g(n,(i,j))=\#\{\mu|(i,j)\notin \mu,~\mu\leq \lambda_n\}$, where $(i,j)$ denotes the $(i,j)$ entry of the Ferrers diagram of $\lambda_n$. Can anyone give some references about $f(n,k)$ and $g(n,(i,j))$ or similar problems of contained partitions?

Comment: For the first question, you are asking for an enumeration of Dyck paths by area. The generating function for this is known, but getting particular values might be a little messy. For the second problem, you can get a sum by adding the counts which pass through particular points. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64664/how-many-dyck-paths-pass-through-x-y I don't know whether the sum simplifies.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments and references, which are very helpful to me.

Comment: See my post

[The number of partitions between two fixed partitions][1]


  [1]: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/161148/the-number-of-partitions-between-two-fixed-partitions/162408#162408